# How to get a particular date between two dates in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

In my MySQL database there is a `dateofjoin (int)` field in the `user` table. `dateofjoin` is inserted like following format:

```
$dateofjoin=mktime(0,0,0,02,22,2015);
```

Now I want list of dates that lie between two dates by select query. where two dates are automatically change in mysql query. I have written like this

```
SELECT *
    FROM user
    WHERE
        (MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(dateofjoin, '%m/%d/%Y')) = MONTH( CURDATE() + INTERVAL 15 DAY)
        AND DAY(STR_TO_DATE(dateofjoin,'%m/%d/%Y')) = DAY(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 15 DAY))
```

Comment: Are your dates actually stored as strings?

Comment: Use the `BETWEEN` operator, which is safe if you are just considering dates and not times.

Comment: no. stored as integer

Comment: Integer of what? Is it seconds since the epoch? YYYYMMDD? Any reason why integer instead of the `DATE` type?

Comment: Your question ("I want a list of dates") doesn't match your SQL ("find users with `dateofjoin` in that interval").

Comment: hope you want to tell i will try using following query
 "SELECT * FROM user WHERE dateofjoin BETWEEN '2015-02-22 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-08 00:00:00".

Comment: @user3688898: yes, that's what you want to be using. If `dateofjoin` is an integer, then convert it to a date first.

Comment: @siride, please explain

Comment: @user3688898: explain which part? Use the query you yourself just posted, but convert `dateofjoin` to a date first.

Comment: Would Jan 1 2015 be stored as 20150101? Or is a UNIX timestamp being stored as the integer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dateofjoin is date or datetime,

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE DATE(dateofjoin) = CURDATE()+INTERVAL 15 days
```

or something like that.  (You haven't specified how you are getting your 2 boundary dates, so I'm just using your 30 days from now.)

However, the fact that you are using STR_TO_DATE() on dateofjoin makes me think maybe you have it stored as a varchar or something? (Why?!)

Comment: it is true i am trying to find all users who joined ON a particular date and every day it will check automatically.

Comment: Are we dealing with datetime or date?

Comment: I see from the comments above that you have your dateofjoin as an integer. If that integer represents a UNIX timestamp then DATE(dateofjoin) should be replaced with DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateofjoin)).  If that integer represents a YYYYMMDD (20150223) integer or a YYYYMMDDHHMMSS (20150223101403) integer then let me know and I'll look at it again. I *think* the simple DATE() surround it will be enough, but I'd have to test if DATE() can take an integer.